# Race condition with Go http server shutdown

Tags: go, goroutine, httpserver

I'm trying to gracefully shut down HTTP server and want to do some cleanup after the server is shut down(once the server stops accepting new connections). However when I run the program with race enabled, it shows `Found 1 data race(s)`.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

func serve(ctx context.Context) (err error) {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "okay")
        },
    ))

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8000",
        Handler: mux,
    }

    go func() {
        if err = srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatalf("listen:%+s\n", err)
        }
    }()

    log.Printf("server started")

    <-ctx.Done()

    log.Printf("server stopped")

    ctxShutDown, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer func() {
        cancel()
    }()

    if err = srv.Shutdown(ctxShutDown); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server Shutdown Failed:%+s", err)
    }

    log.Printf("server exited properly")

    if err == http.ErrServerClosed {
        err = nil
    }

    return
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    go func() {
        oscall := <-c
        log.Printf("system call:%+v", oscall)
        cancel()
    }()

    if err := serve(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to serve:+%v\n", err)
    }
}
```

Steps to reproduce

`go build -race main.go && ./main`, after the server is started then initiate a SIGINT with `CTRL+C`

How can I get rid of the race condition in this code?

Comment: On what lines ? The go race detector print which lines produces a racy access

Comment: You are writing and reading `err` (the named return variable) concurrently in `func serve`.

Comment: If you are asigning to a variable within an `if` statement, the point is to constrain the scope to the block and you should use the short variable declaration.

Comment: Hi, thanks @leafbebop. The race condition was with accessing the named return variable err

Comment: Side-note: instead of `defer func() { cancel() }()`, you can simply write `defer cancel()`

Comment: FYI from [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe): `ListenAndServe always returns a non-nil error` therefore the `err != nil` check is redundant.